# Ubuntu 12.04 works when installed boot-repair now one more problem

Tags: 12.04

Ubuntu 12.04 works when installed boot-repair now one more problem that after installation it give option boot ubuntu or win.
when i put windows xp cd and delete delete drive e: in which ubuntu is installed and i save settings when i restart pc it give a black screen;

Answer (score 2):

You have just deleted ubuntu drive without removing mbr.

Fix it following - 
http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-mbr-xp-vista/

Comment: yes i have deleted ubuntu drive

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)** from a CD. (this will fix the MBR)